# Как подсветить строки разным цветом в зависимости от значений в строке?

Tags: javafx

У меня получилось подсветить всю строку как мне нужно используя вот этот код

```
[SRC java]
table.setRowFactory((TableView<MyClass> paramP) -> new TableRow<MyClass>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(MyClassrow, boolean paramBoolean) {
                if (row != null) {
                    switch (row.getColor()) {
                        case 1:
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: LIGHTCORAL; -fx-text-background-color: black;");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: skyblue; -fx-text-background-color: black;");
                            break;
                        default:
                            setStyle(null);
                    }

                } else {
                    setStyle(null);
                }
                super.updateItem(row, paramBoolean);
            }
        });
[/SRC]
```

теперь мне нужно подсветить одну ячейку, текущую, т.е. ту на которой установлен курсор.
пробую делать так

```
[SRC java]
table.setCellFactory((TableColumn<MyClass, Integer> param) -> new TableCell<MyClass, Integer>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
                if (item != null) {
                    setText(item.toString());
                    if (table.getSelectionModel().getFocusedIndex() == getTableRow().getIndex()) {
                        setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
                    } else {
                        setStyle(null);
                    }
                }
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
            }
        });
[/SRC]
```

подсветка делается, НО только при открытии таблицы или когда нужная мне ячейка выходит за рамки видимости и возвращается обратно (например если список большой и скролить вверх/вниз чтобы ячейка вышла за рамки видимости)

вопрос: как принудительно перерисовать ячейку при смене выбранной строки?

может есть какие то методы TableView.Repaint или TableView.Update, или листнер какой-нибудь?

Answer (score 1):

Прямого метода нет,есть грязный, но рабочий хак - прятать и показывать колонки. Реализуется примерно таким способом.

```
table.getColumns().forEach(column - > Platform.runLater(() - > {
    column.setVisible(false);
    column.setVisible(true);
}));
```